# Google-maps? Or something else?

Tags: google-maps, mapping

I need something like Google-maps, usable on a commercial project. Can I use GoogleMaps? What if they should change the terms of service? Would I be better with somethin elike Open Street Map?

I need full coverage for North America, but also for Europe and Asia.

Which might be best? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to avoid using Google Maps based on concerns over changes to the terms of service would be a mistake. Google Maps is very well established and for Google to compromise the service in some way, would mean alienating a massive number of people, something Google is certainly not going to do.

From a technical standpoint, I talk about my [reasons for using Google Maps here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885740/map-technologies-for-the-web-such-as-google-maps/888768#888768).

Answer (score 1):

Google does not own the data, they are themselves licensees of [Tele Atlas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tele_Atlas). This Wikipedia page has details about the deal, that may be enough to answer your question.

Yes, the terms could change anytime. Yes, perhaps what you want to do is already forbidden.

OpenStreetMap is not reliable enough yet for most uses. It's a great pastime though if you have a GPS and like this sort of thing (I do).

If you gave more details in your question someone would be able to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Google has started creating its own maps in the US, and it probably won't stop there. I shook the LBS market up few weeks ago http://searchengineland.com/no-more-teleatlas-google-goes-it-alone-for-maps-data-27584

Comment: Yes, I noticed this on my own link after posting it :) I can see some of the data they need being a side-product of streetview, but the method they used in the US (start with governmental public data) will not work everywhere. Hope the user-contribution side of Google Maps doesn't divert people from OpenStreetMap — one CDDB fiasco is enough!

Comment: more details: hmmm, still quite vague. Certainly don't want to to anythign forbidden by Google, jsut what the API offers.

I am guessing a few 100, max few k vehicles per US state. Maps at different reosultion, from statewide to a few blocks (so, standard zoom). 

Ability to look up a drier in a databse then show his location on the map.

Vice-versa, enetr a location (street name or lat/long) and find the nearest vehicle.

Jsut “Standard fleet managem,ent stuff” - whatever that is.

Comment: As a simple example, my favorite GPS application on the iPhone interfaces with both Google Maps and OpenStreetMap, but refuses to cache the former, claiming the terms prevent it. If your application is not for general distribution, you're probably fine.